# Laravel, artisan "generating optimized class loader" after every command

Tags: php, laravel

I have an annoyance with Laravel at the moment. Running 4.1.27. After almost every command I issue in the terminal involving `php artisan`, it ends with writing `generating optimized class loader` taking 20-40 seconds, making me wait a lot every time.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I take it you're using linux/osx as you've said "terminal", so open your terminal and type `alias |grep artisan` to rule out the possibility of running an aliased command

Comment: No aliases. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: Same problem here, no aliases either. On my mac the generation ocurres really fast, on my ubuntu vm it has this huge delay. I'm guessing php versions! 5.4 runs smooth, 5.5 delays. Anyone has a similar env?

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in PHP core. Updated it from 5.5.13 to 5.5.16 (current latest) and all problems are gone.

[Here a detailed description](https://www.trafex.nl/2014/06/17/php-5-5-13-breaks-backwards-compatibility/).